# Canceling changes to the bound textbox on Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a textbox that is bound to an object property. How can I undo changes to the property if user edits that control and does not want to apply changes?

I know that I can just save old values before editing and restore them in case user cancels editing. However, that solution eliminates most of the benefits of data binding as all bound properties would have to be reset manually.

Here is XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding BindingText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And the code in the PageLoaded handler:

```
DataContext = App.Binder; // Set data context for the page
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one way data binding, but that will not serve you the purpose I think.

Also remember that data-binding is provided so that developer do not have to manually do the extra lines of code. It is there to automate the common task. To have that manual control you have to do that manually. I know this is not the answer you may want, but that's the way it is.

---

Now I think you can setup that using an extra property/variable and 2 one-way binding.

Let this object property be binded to that variable , i.e. when this property changes the actual object property changes(only one way)

The text box is binded to object property(one way) so when object property changes then textbox reflects it.

And use a submit button which would change the temp variables value according to the textbox.

tempVar ----> object property
object property ----> textbox
textbox changes tempVar manually.

But it's still not a direct answer, but a workaround(with data bindings).

Comment: I think that it is a very standard pattern where user goes to the edit page and can either accept changes or discard them. Windows Phone binding mechanism works perfectly when it has to show data and accept changes but there is no easy way to cancel. I cannot believe that such basic functionality could be missing. After all every page/form/screen has apply and cancel buttons. Even babies know that :) Maybe I am just looking at it wrong?

Comment: Yeah and in pages/forms you have to implement what will happen when either button is pressed. I myself don't like things going in auto mode and want precise manual control, but it is not always possible in rapid development environment, I guess. It is my opinion.